# Plot values without timeshift for different time ranges on Grafana

Tags: plot, visualization, grafana, influxdb

I have a InfluxDB which basically has columns (value, metric name, timestamp)
I am collecting the metric values in db from time x to time y.
Now, On Grafana dashboard I want to plot a metric for different time ranges on the same panel but without timeshift.
So y axis will be value and x axis should be nothing, since I will query to select metric from time x to time y and other query would be select "same metric " from time y to time z, so that I can compare the metric values at different instances of time without having to worry about timeshift concept.

Comment: It's only possible in Flux, the new query language for influxDB. [Look here](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.24/functions/built-in/transformations/timeshift/) for  documentation of the timeshift function.

Comment: I tried with flux plugin in Grafana, but I am getting network forbidden error(403) even after making changes in influxdb config file. I updated http_enabled= true in config file

Comment: You also need to enable Flux itself in the config file. Did you make sure InfluxDB actually uses **Your** config file?  What system are you on ?

Comment: Yeah, I updated flux-enabled also to be true. How do I find out if my db is using that config file. I am working on Windows.

Comment: It works for me when I add the config file as an argument. I run InfluxDB as a service to do that, I use nssm for that:

Install nssm (or another suitable tool)
Create a new service
Provide the path to influxdb.exe
Add this argument (alter path accordingly) to the service: config "C:\path\to\your\influxdb\config